# Vectorised np.random.choice with varying probabilities

Tags: python, numpy, random, scikit-learn

I've trained a machine learning model using sklearn and want to simulate the result by sampling the predictions according to the predict_proba probabilities. So I want to do something like

```
samples = np.random.choice(a = possible_outcomes, size = (n_data, n_samples), p = probabilities)

Where probabilities would be is an (n_data, n_possible_outcomes) array
```

But np.random.choice only allows 1d arrays for the p argument. I've currently gotten around this using a for-loop like the following implementation

```
sample_outcomes = np.zeros((len(probs), n_samples))
for i in trange(len(probs)):
    sample_outcomes[i, :] = np.random.choice(outcomes, s = n_samples, p=probs[i])
```

but that's relatively slow. Any suggestions to speed this up would be much appreciated!

Comment: you can just sample from an index list and then take the elements from the list

Comment: In your example of a for-loop implementation, `sample_outcomes` is apparently initialized as a 1d array `np.zeros(len(probs))`, but you index `sample_outcomes` as a 2d array. That seems odd.

Comment: @jjramsey sorry that's a typo and I can't  seem to be able to edit it

Comment: Are you running into the problem described here?: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315915/am-i-not-allowed-to-edit-my-own-question

Comment: @jjramsey fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want a vectorize way of applying [choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)
several times and each time with a different probabilities vector.
You could implement this by hand as follows:

```
import numpy as np

# for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# number of samples
k = 5

# possible outcomes
outcomes = np.arange(10)

# generate a random probability matrix for 15 runs
probabilities = np.random.random((15, 10))
probs = probabilities / probabilities.sum(1)[:, None]

# generate the choices by picking those probabilities above a random generated number
# the higher the value in probs the higher the probability to pick it
choices = probs - np.random.random((15, 10))

# to pick the top k using argpartition need to multiply by -1
choices = -1 * choices

# pick the top k values
res = outcomes[np.argpartition(choices, k, axis=1)][:, :k]

# flatten to match the expected output
print(res.flatten())
```

**Output**

```
[1 8 2 5 3 6 4 8 7 0 1 5 9 3 7 1 4 9 0 8 5 0 4 3 6 8 5 1 2 6 5 3 2 0 6 5 4
 2 3 7 7 9 4 6 1 3 6 4 2 1 4 9 3 0 1 6 9 2 3 8 5 4 7 6 1 5 3 8 2 1 1 0 9 7
 4]
```

In the above example the code sample 5 (`k`) elements from a population of 10 (`outcomes`) 15 times each time with a different probability vector (`probs` with a shape of 15 by 10).

Comment: yes that's right I want to draw a sample with a different probability vector for each data point..This solution seems to work well for my solution and is around 200x faster on an array of length 1200000.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with replacement as well? I don't  actually need that for the application but I'm curious

Comment: @Rhys I think one idea will be to generate a matrix of random float as above multiply by the number of items and round it to an integer, this will generate the indices to apply in the population

Comment: I voted +1 here but I do not see how to prove that the method gives the correct distribution of probability. Pointers to the proof, please?

Comment: I am surprised, well, sum of extractions for k=1 fail to reproduce the original probs vector, but the error seems to be well controlled, what magic is this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can do, if I understand your question correctly:

```
import numpy as np
#create a list of indices
index_list = np.arange(len(possible_outcomes))
# sample indices based on the probabilities
choice = np.random.choice(a = index_list, size = n_samples, p = probabilities)
# get samples based on randomly chosen indices
samples = possible_outcomes[choice]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making sure I understand you problem correctly.  Can you just create `samples` as an array of size `n_data * n_samples` and then use the resize method to get it to the right size?

```
samples = np.random.choice(a = possible_outcomes, size = n_data * n_samples, p = probabilities)
samples.resize((n_data, n_samples))
```